# How to use shebang AND import modules from parallel directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, project, python-import

I have a project with the following structure:

```
project-name/
|
|___ __init__.py
|___ main.py
|
|___ toolA/
|    |___ __init__.py
|    |___ toolA.py
|
|___ toolB/
|    |___ __init__.py
|    |___ toolB.py
|
|___ common/
     |___ __init__.py
     |___ utils.py
```

I need tools A and B (scripts `toolA.py` and `toolB.py`) to be able to import some functions located in `utils.py`.

Furthermore, `toolA.py` and `toolB.py` are meant to be part of a toolchain (implemented by `main.py`) but they also need to be standalone tools. That is why I 've decided to make them executables, with a shebang in both of them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
```

I 've found some solutions with the `-m` flag when executing `python`, but this is not an option due to the shebang. Is there any way to achieve this? I have found numerous posts and solutions but none worked for me. Ideally, I need something like this, without any further configuration (like editing paths and such):

```py
# toolA.py or toolB.py
from project-name.common import utils
```

or

```py
# toolA.py or toolB.py
from common import utils
```

P.S. I am not sure whether the `__init__.py`s are needed or not, or if I have to put something in them (they are currently blank).

Comment: Using the shebang should behave identically to just doing the console command `python3.7 utils.py` - this shouldn't mess with imports compared to just doing that. As for the `__init__.py` files, those just need to exist for python to recognize a folder as a module, they don't need to contain anything.

Comment: Nevertheless, I get the following error from the python interactive shell (inside `toolA` folder):

`>>> from common import utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
>>> from ..common import utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`